# wp_get_attachment_image_url wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I would like get an image size 640x640 and used `wp_get_attachment_image_url` function.
Actually, this size of image is not available in the content upload. How can I get the image which size is maximum close value 640x640?.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you can find the answer and very good example at official documentation of that function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_url/

A little summary:

```
add_image_size( 'image-size-640', 640, 640, true ); //resize, crop in functions.php

$img_id = 6; //need to get it dynamically

$cropped_image = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $img_id, 'image-size-640' ); //use custom set size
```

After you add new sizes, WordPress has to regenerate the images. Best plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Comment: Can't you add an array for the width and height without registering another custom size